# AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'save'. During save the file

Tags: python, excel, save

I am beginner for python(3.5.1).
Please someone help me. this is  the code..

```
import os
import xlrd
import xlwt
import openpyxl

book = xlwt.Workbook('C:/python3.5')
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("PySheet1") 
sheet1.write(1,1,'anuj')
book.save('temp.xls')
```

Comment: Can you please format your code by indenting it by 4 spaces or selecting all of it and pressing `ctrl + k`.

Comment: http://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to call that constructor with a file path: `class xlwt.Workbook.Workbook(encoding=’ascii’, style_compression=0)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
#xlrd, xlutils and xlwt modules need to be installed.  
#Can be done via pip install <module>
from xlrd import open_workbook

from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook("names.xls")
wb = copy(rb)

s = wb.get_sheet(0)
s.write(0,0,'A1')
wb.save('names.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use book.save()

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(engine='openpyxl')
writer.book.save("filename.xlsx")
```